# Can't connect to Push Extension Service

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

i added Push Extension Service (target) to my project               [iOS 10 Rich Notifications Integration](https://www.pushwoosh.com/docs/ios-10-rich-notifications-integration)

It can't connect to process (and it doesn't work - can't change payload). Xcode only once connected to process by "Debug - Attach to process by PID or Name".
Now, it waits for "Waiting for attach" status.

Xcode 9.4.1
Running device IPhone 7 Plus 11.4

Comment: Add the screenshot of the issue that you are facing.

Comment: I got the same problem. I checked the Extension project: 1. deployment target is less than the device OS in service extension, and >= 10.0. 2. payload should contain "mutable-content": 1 . but is still not working! when I send Payload ,The extension program is still waiting to attach. and the main App received a remote message for backgroud model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, i understood - Push Extension Service is activated when you got Notification with "mutable-content":1